# Calling shutdown and closesocket twice on same socket

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

In my application I call `shutdown` and `closesocket` functions twice on the same socket. I know this is not right thing to do and I have to ensure that these functions are called only once. But why don't either of these calls fail when called a second time?

If the handle of `m_Socket` is `1500`, then what will it's value be when `shutdown` and `closesocket` functions are called on it?

```
shutdown(m_SocServer, 2);
closesocket(m_SocServer);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First one must distinguish two different things:

1. Performing operations on a socket, some of which may bring it in an unusable state.
2. Terminating the socket handle.

Calling `shutdown` with parameter 2 (which is `SD_BOTH`) is (1). That is, you flush all the pending out buffer, plus discard all the receive buffer. So that you can't read/write anymore. However you still hold a valid socket handle. You still may query/set its options if you want. For instance, one could call `getpeername` on it to discover the address you were connected to.
Also, depending on the implementation, calling `shutdown` again doesn't have to result in an error. Maybe it has an accumulative effect.

On the other hand calling `closesocket` is (2). Once you called it - you can't do anything with that socket handle. It's now invalid.

If you socket has a value of 1500 - it will still have it, even after a call to `closesocket`. Because it's just a variable. It's like asking what value will have the pointer after you `delete` it.

However this socket value (1500) is no more valid. You can't call any socket function with this value.

Moreover, if you create another socket meanwhile - it's very likely to receive the same number. Here you may find yourself in a more severe problem - doing actions on another socket without noticing it.

For some it's a good practice assigning `INVALID_SOCKET` value to a socket variable right after you call `closesocket` on it.

P.S.
Perhaps calling `shutdown` + `closesocket` don't fail specifically because you're closing another socket.

Answer (score 5):

Whether you get an error or not after calling `closesocket` the first time depends on what the rest of your code is doing.

Once you call `closesocket`, that socket identifier is free and could be returned again by another call to `socket`.  If you call `closesocket` again, you are not closing your original socket but the newly reopened one

Answer (score 1):

They do fail. Try to following snippet.

```
SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
closesocket(s);   // OK

shutdown(s, 2);   // fails
closesocket(s);   // fails
```