# what happens if tried to close an already closed socket winsock?

Tags: c++, c, winsock

What will happen if i call closesocket(m_socket) two times?
After first call the socket will get closed.
Whether after second call something will happen that is not good for the program or application. or it will just return a error that i can ignore.

Comment: may be this should help [L1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115561/calling-shutdown-and-closesocket-twice-on-same-socket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx

> Note that the socket descriptor passed in the s parameter may immediately be reused by the system as soon as closesocket function is issued. As a result, it is not reliable to expect further references to the socket descriptor passed in the s parameter to fail with the error WSAENOTSOCK.

I'd interpret that as meaning you should be careful not to close the socket twice when any intermediate code may have done anything involving a descriptor - which includes opening files and other sockets - rather than a necessary blanket prohibition, but really this is fragile and you should be coding to avoid the possibility.  It may make sense to assign INVALID_SOCKET to the variable you're using to hold the socket descriptor, allowing you to check for that before calling closesocket again or (worse) ensuring a side-effect-free failure of that second call.